# Rails Application Cannot Connect to Local MySQL Server Through Named-Pipe/Socket --- Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, pipe, mysql-connector, mysql2

I'm trying to set up a Rails application to use a MySQL server on my local machine for development.  I have successfully compiled the `mysql2` gem against MySQLConnector/C; although I have received the same error using  libmysql.dll bundled with my installation of MySQL Server.  When I attempt to `rake db:create`, the application fails to connect to the MySQL Server.

MySQL is configured on my machine as a Windows service, started automatically for local-only connections through named-pipes; TCP-IP has been completely disabled.  The name of the socket in my `my.ini` file is `mysql`.

My `database.yml` file for my Rails application looks something like this:

> development:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   encoding: utf8   reconnect: false
>   database: application_dev
>   pool: 5
>   username: root
>
> password: **********
>
> host: localhost
>   socket: mysql
>
> test:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   encoding: utf8   reconnect: false
>   database: application_test
>   pool: 5
>   username: root
>
> password: **********
>
> host: localhost
>   socket: mysql

And the error I'm recieving is:

> D:\Dropbox\Programming\Ruby\application>rake db:create
>   (in D:/Dropbox/Programming/Ruby/application)
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"application_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"**********", "host"=>"localhost", "
>   socket"=>"mysql"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnec
>   t"=>false, "database"=>"applicaton_dev", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password
>   "=>"**********", "host"=>"localhost", "socket"=>"mysql"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with the following Ruby/Rails/MySQL distribution:

`ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]`

`Rails 3.0.7`

`mysql2 rubygem 0.2.7`

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.11, for Win32 (x86)`

`mysql Connector/C 6.0.0`

I've tried reinstalling MySQL Server and enabling TCP-IP connections, and it just hangs instead of failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the port number in your database.yml adding this parameter:

```
port: 3306 (or whatever your mysql port has)
```